# cryptacquirecontext throws "Access denied" in Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, c++, native-code

cryptacquirecontext throws "Access denied" Error in Windows Server 2008(only one pc),the same code working fine with all other PC including Windows Server 2008 also.Any suggestions?

Note:The currently logged in user have full permission to access the folder "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA".

Answer (score 0):

The Process Monitor(Procmon.exe) reported the actual problem to that PC.